# Get all the data of a field but populate only 10 of them in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have `User` model with this `friends` schema:

```
friends: [{
      type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }],
```

I tried this:

```
const user = await User.findById({ _id: userID })
        .populate({ path: 'friends', options: { limit: 10 } })
```

this works.... but it actually loads and `populate` only 10 of the friends. I need to load all of them to display the count of the friends and populate 10 to display user avatar and such things...

How can I do this?

Also I have simimar problem with this schema:

```
comments: [{
      user: {
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      comment: {
        type: String
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
    }]
```

I tried this:

It populate all of the `comments.user` but how should I do this here because this:

```
const user = await User.findById({ _id: userID })
        .populate({ path: 'comments.user', options: { limit: 10 } })
```

doesn't limit them....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to fix that by using aggregation + populate kind of like this (untested):

```
var result = User.aggregate([{
    $match: { // filter by user id
        _id: userID
    }
}, {
    $addFields: { // add count of friends
        numberOfFriends: { $size: "$friends" }
    }
}]);
```

and then

```
User.populate(result, { path: "friends", options: { limit: 10 } }, /* your callback */);
```